# Use user (and not service account) token for kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, entra-id, oauth

I've a Kubernetes deployment on Azure (AKS) and I also deployed the k8s dashboard.

I've connected the k8s deployment to our Azure Active Directory (AAD) so we can use the kubectl command with our AAD login (steps here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-ad-integration-cli).

I also want to be able to authenticate the dashboard through AAD. I deployed pusher oauth2_proxy (https://github.com/pusher/oauth2_proxy) in front of my server to achieve this.

My problem is: I can give kubernetes dashboard service account admin-rights and use that token to authenticate. This means that everyone who authenticates against our AD will get full access rights. But, I need to be able to filter permissions depending on the user logged in. In oauth2_proxy, there is a flag --pass-authorization-header (which adds "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" to the headers) but it seems that you can only use a service account token in the dashboard and not user tokens.

Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I think following approach might work.

Create a [basic group and add members using Azure Active Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-groups-create-azure-portal) on the Azure part.

As for Kubernetes part, you should be using [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) for [Control access to cluster resources using role-based access control and Azure Active Directory identities in Azure Kubernetes Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-ad-rbac).

You will be able to limit each groups to desired `namespace` or certain actions like only `watch`.

Here is a nice example of using [External OAUTH Authentication](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/auth/oauth-external-auth) with Kuberetes.

Comment: I tried with this. I was able to login, but the problem is that I can't select the rights per user. I can select same permissions for everyone with service account, but not put permissions per user based on the token generated by the proxy.

Comment: You need to create groups and set permissions per group, not per user.